# Reduce List to longest String in the List with Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to figure out how to create a function that takes a List of Strings and returns a new list that only contains the longest string in the list.

I'm having a hard time figuring out several aspects of this problem including how to keep track of the maximum and change it when there is a new longest string. Do I need to use an Effect / Task?

Example: a function that takes ["one", "two", "three"] and returns ["three"] since it is the longest string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a function that gives you the longest string of a list:

```
List.sortBy String.length >> List.reverse >> List.take 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fold your list, keeping track of the longest string along the way:

```elm
import String exposing (length)

findLongest = List.foldr (\x y -> if length x > length y then x else y) ""
```

This has a performance advantage over `List.sortBy`, since `foldr` is taking a single swipe at the list, while sorting has to sort all the items.

Comment: Unless absolutely necessary because it's causing a noticeable performance drain, you should never trade readable code for less readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: You don't need to use an Effect or Task.

A longest string function can be defined as follows:

```
import String exposing (length)

longerString : String -> String -> String
longerString s1 s2 = if length s2 > length s1 then s2 else s1

longestString : List String -> String
longestString = List.foldr longerString ""
```

Then you can use it like:

```
longestString ["one", "two", "three"] -- returns "three"
```

If you want the result as a list with one element, that is also possible.

```
[ longestString [ "one", "two", "three" ] ] -- returns [ "three" ]
```